# How to display detailed row in TableView#2 when row in TableView #1 is tapped? (Swift - iOS)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am kinda stuck in my iPhone app project (Swift, iOS, Xcode 7, using a StoryBoard), and I am hoping someone would be kind enough to give me a helping hand.

I am trying to link two Tableviews in such a way that when the user (me!) taps any row (each row = day of the week) in the 1st TableView it takes him to a more detailed row in the 2nd TableView; in a row, the user would enter info for 4 items, and in that 2nd TableView, the user would be able to add as many similar rows as he wishes to again enter different info for the 4 items such Time, Event, Place etc.

When I tried to create that 2nd TableView (dragged ViewController into StoryBoard, inserted TableView object, added 1 dynamic cell), I simply was unable to link it with the 1st TableView...

Voilà... Any help will be hugely appreciated as I am new to that environment. Thanks in anticipation.

Cheers,

Laroms

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to link a NavigationController from one TableView to  the second TableView. Make sure you right-click and drag the action to the appropriate methods.